# Running a .exe file on a Windows machine over ssh not working

Tags: python, windows, exe, openssh

I have to run a .exe file which takes 2 arguments like this-

```
File.exe Arg1 Arg2
```

I have openSSH setup and running on both the machines. Now I try to run the File using
 `os.system("ssh remote@ip cd C:/path/to/File;\"./File.exe Arg1 Arg2\"")`

However nothing happens, even though there is no error received. Everything works fine. I tried running ls, pwd, etc. and they work fine. Moreover I have also tried running a .bat file and it also works fine.
What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably (but it depends upon the [command interpreter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command-line_interface#Command-line_interpreter), e.g. your [Unix shell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_shell) if your local machine is a Unix system, or [`cmd.exe`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cmd.exe) if your local machine runs Windows) your argument to `os.system`, that is the string `ssh remote@ip cd C:/path/to/File;"./File.exe Arg1 Arg2"`  is parsed as a composite command, that is a sequence of *two* sub-commands separated by a semi-colon:

```
ssh remote@ip cd C:/path/to/File
```

which justs runs a (useless) `cd` on the `ip` host as user `remote` and nothing else

then

```
"./File.exe Arg1 Arg2"
```

which tries (and fails) to run (on your local system) an [executable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable) named `./File.exe Arg1 Arg2` (files can have spaces, but that is ugly and you should avoid that)

Perhaps you should do

```
os.system("ssh remote@ip 'cd C:/path/to/File; ./File.exe Arg1 Arg2'")
```

and you should test the result code of [`os.system`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html)

Actually, if you are coding that `./File.exe`, I would recommend having some program flag to change the [working directory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Working_directory) (the `-C` flag of [`make`](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/) or of `tar` could be inspirational) in its code.

Remember that each [process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_(computing)) (including your shell or your command interpreter) has its *own* working directory. Details are operating system specific.

Comment: Thanks for the response. The problem was resolved with space separated commands. The desired new files were generated and all. The main issue why I thought nothing was working was because the File.exe when launched from remote computer itself opened a **new** window on screen. The command issued through ssh didn't do that. Although I don't actually need it, but is there any way to display that window on the remote computer's screen?

Comment: This is a very different question and it is operating system specific (depends of the OS on both local and remote machines). If the remote system is Linux, consider using `ssh -X` for [Xorg](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X.Org_Server). Otherwise read about [VNC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_Network_Computing)